# Nuget Update causes Errors in MainActivity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Today I updated my Nuget packages in my Visual Studio Xamarin Forms with a full Android project and an empty IOS one. I updated the packets on the entire project, the IOS project and the Android project. However, when I go into my MainActivity class, anything related to the Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Essentials packets claim that they need an assembly reference even though ive never had any there, and the ones it's asking for don't seem to exist. My Xamarin is up to date, and so is my target version. I have tried cleaning my solution, restarting Visual Studio, and deleting and reinstalling all nuget packets, your help is appreciated (Note: this has happened on every single Xamarin Forms project I have updated the packets on)

Comment: Which package did you update? Can you provide more information about the error you met?

Comment: Could just be an issue with bin/obj files not being updated, deleting them and restarting should generally solve your issue.